# Any way to line up the end of TRON Legacy-style grid half-way between top and bottom regardless of resolution?

Tags: html, css, 3d

## Expected Behavior, Problem, and Screenshots

At 1920x1080 (100% scale) and in 3840x2160 at 200% scale, the end of the grid lines up nicely with the horizon of the sky.

[image: A web page in Chrome giving it an illusion of a grid within 3D space]

The screenshot above is what I consider to be an expected behavior. The screenshot below is not.

Now here's a screenshot but this time it's in full screen. Notice the end of the grid does not line up with the sky's horizon.

[image]

### Note

To make it look like a web page, I've added some line of text from the movie, TRON: Legacy but modified the text to make it my own. The images captured in 3840x2160 have been reduced to 1920x1080 in order to save some bandwidth.

## Code

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
  background: #87CEEB linear-gradient(to bottom, #408aa5, #7cc3e0 43.75%, #bce9ff 50%, #327e99 62.5%, #01617b);
  color: white;
}

.grid {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 900px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  /*
     * Specifying a percentage for perspective() won't work because the
     * grid will be in 2D instead of 3D.
     */
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(60.5deg) scale(8) translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* 
     * Clip the extended "after" pseudo element in order to give it an illusion of a moving
     * grid.
     */
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Add a gradient that fades to the horizon. */

.grid:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, transparent 75%, rgba(240, 248, 255, 0.875));
  z-index: -1;
}


/* The grid. */

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -900px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 200 200' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Crect x='10' y='10' width='180' height='180' rx='20' stroke='white' stroke-width='5' fill='none' /%3E%3C/svg%3E") repeat;
  background-size: 3.125%;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 1800px;
  animation: slidegrid 12s forwards linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slidegrid {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.maintitle {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="maintitle">The Grid</h1>
  <p>A digital frontier.</p>
  <p>I tried to picture clusters of information as they moved through the computer.</p>
  <p>What do they look like?</p>
  <p>Trains? Bicycles?</p>
  <p>Were the circuits like lightrails?</p>
  <p>I kept dreaming of a world I thought I'd never seen.</p>
  <p>And then, one day...</p>
  <p style="font-size: 2em; text-align: center;"><strong>I got in!</strong></p>
</div>
```

Try the code above and resize the height of the browser window. Notice that the grid stays the same and does not line up with the horizon.

An element with the "grid" class is setup to be in 3D space. I faked the grid background to make it look like it is reflecting from the sky. An element with the "container" class is what I consider the container to be a "see-through screen" or perhaps a "holographic web page" unless the viewport becomes narrow. Also, notice that the "container" class has a position of relative and z-index set to 1. The grid (SVG) along with the gradient that fades to the horizon shows through in front of the container instead of behind.

(And yes, I made a slight typo in HTML for "I've never seen" but I decided to leave the screenshots alone for now.)

## Summary

I want to create an illusion of the background that makes it look like it's in 3D and line up the end of the grid by 50% of the height of the viewport. How can I accomplish so that the end of the grid touches the horizon?

Comment: you can use and reset transform-origin , default values are : center center.

Comment: This seems like this will have to be done using JavaScript. Hmm... Not what I want when it comes to progressive enhancement. Thanks.

Comment: I'm thinking of a camera that is positioned about halfway between the top and bottom of the viewport where the grid is at the bottom of the viewport. That would seem impossible to do with CSS unless I get into using WebGL, but WebGL does require JavaScript, am I right?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Having a combined block of HTML/CSS code in one block of code would make it a lot easier for anyone to copy code at once instead of copying different parts of the code. That way, I can just copy it all in one go into a text editor and run the code from there. Besides, Notepad in Windows does not have a pre-formatted HTML code ready for me to paste my code in. I'm actually using Vim in Linux.

Comment: I turned your code into a working snippet so your code can be run live right here and be copy/paste into an answer from a click;) that was the idea. The dnippet can also reformat thé code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the sliding bg is suppossed to be layed on the bottom half, you can set it there and set `transform-origin` from its own top

example :

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
body {
  background: #87ceeb
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      #408aa5,
      #7cc3e0 43.75%,
      #bce9ff 50%,
      #327e99 62.5%,
      #01617b
    ) fixed;
  color: white;
}

.grid {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50vh;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transform-origin: center top;
  /*
     * Specifying a percentage for perspective() won't work because the
     * grid will be in 2D instead of 3D.
     */
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(60.5deg) scale(1.5, 0.5) translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* 
     * Clip the extended "after" pseudo element in order to give it an illusion of a moving
     * grid.
     */
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Add a gradient that fades to the horizon. */
.grid:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    transparent,
    transparent 75%,
    rgba(240, 248, 255, 0.875)
  );
  z-index: -1;
}
/* The grid. */
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -900px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)
    url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 200 200' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Crect x='10' y='10' width='180' height='180' rx='20' stroke='white' stroke-width='5' fill='none' /%3E%3C/svg%3E")
    repeat;
  background-size: 3.125%;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 1800px;
  animation: slidegrid 12s forwards linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slidegrid {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.maintitle {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="maintitle">The Grid</h1>
    <p>A digital frontier.</p>
    <p>I tried to picture clusters of information as they moved through the computer.</p>
    <p>What do they look like?</p>
    <p>Trains? Bicycles?</p>
    <p>Were the circuits like lightrails?</p>
    <p>I kept dreaming of a world I thought I'd never seen.</p>
    <p>And then, one day...</p>
    <p style="font-size: 2em; text-align: center;"><strong>I got in!</strong></p>
  </div>
```